# Calling class method in python thread queue

Tags: python, multithreading, class

Could someone please shed some light on why this threaded code to call a classes' method never completes?

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class SimpleThing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print self.name

class ThingSpawner(object):
    def __init__(self, name_list):
        self.things  = [SimpleThing(name) for name in name_list]
        self.thread_queue = Queue()

    def run(self):
        for thing in self.things:
            t = Thread(target=thing.print_name, name=thing.name)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            self.thread_queue.put(t)
        self.thread_queue.join()

thing_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'llama', 'bat']

sp = ThingSpawner(thing_list)
sp.run()
```

The code will clearly run the `print_name` method, but does not `join()` and exit.

Also, what is the neatest way to modify this code so that the `join()` completes? The motivation is to use an existing python control class for a bit of hardware, and allows you to call a (very slow) method of the control class in parallel. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are doing

```
self.thread_queue.put(t)
```

You are putting some threads into the `Queue`, obviously. However, i'm not really sure why. You never use that queue again for anything, and it's completely unnecessary. To make matters worse, you then call

```
self.thread_queue.join()
```

Which basically waits forever for the queue to empty, which never happens, because you never empty it or do anything with it.

If I copy paste all your code, but without any `Queue` at all, everything is fine...

```
from threading import Thread

class SimpleThing(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self):
        print self.name

class ThingSpawner(object):
    def __init__(self, name_list):
        self.things  = [SimpleThing(name) for name in name_list]

    def run(self):
        for thing in self.things:
            t = Thread(target=thing.print_name, name=thing.name)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

thing_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'llama', 'bat']

sp = ThingSpawner(thing_list)
sp.run()
```

However that's not what you want! Because your threads are daemons they will exit when the main program exits, even if they are not done yet (if I add some delay like `sleep(1)` before printing the name for example). You should call `join()` on the threads, not the queue, if you want to wait for them to finish. So we'll return the threads first:

```
    def run(self):
        all_threads = []
        for thing in self.things:
            t = Thread(target=thing.print_name, name=thing.name)
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            all_threads.append(t)
        return all_threads
```

And when we `run` we'll do this:

```
threads = sp.run()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ofer for the clear answer, which I've just accepted -- I am indeed not using the queue properly! Having reacquainted myself with queues now you've pointed out my error, for prosperity, here's an alternative approach using a queue:

```
from Queue import Queue
from threading import Thread

class SimpleThing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, q):
        self.name = name

    def print_name(self, q):
        print self.name
        q.get()
        q.task_done()

class ThingSpawner(object):
    def __init__(self, name_list):
        self.thread_queue = Queue()
        self.things  = [SimpleThing(name, self.thread_queue) for name in name_list]


    def run(self):
        for thing in self.things:
            t = Thread(target=thing.print_name, name=thing.name, args=(self.thread_queue,))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()
            self.thread_queue.put(t)
        self.thread_queue.join()

thing_list = ['cat', 'dog', 'llama', 'bat']

sp = ThingSpawner(thing_list)
sp.run()
```

[This tutorial](https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/) on threading and queues was useful once I understood my mistake.